# Writing every N elements in list to multiple text files

Tags: python, pandas, loops, text-files

I am trying to write every N-number of items in a nested list to multiple .txt files. The tricky part is writing each group of N- elements in a text file.

My list:
`list = ['item1a item1b item1c','item2a','item3a item3b','item4a item4b item4c','item5a','item6a item6b','item7a item7b item7c','item8a','item9a item9b']`

I would like the following .txt file outputs:

```
text1.txt: item1a item1b item1c \n item2a \n item3a item3b
text2.txt: item4a item4b item4c \n item5a \n item6a item6b
text3.txt: item7a item7b item7c \n item8a \n item9a item9b
```

---

Currently, each nested list is written to a single .txt file. The groupings aren't what I need. I'm so close! I think this should be a minor fix.

For example:

```
text1.txt: item1a item1b item1c
text2.txt: item2a
text3.txt: item3a item3b
```

---

My code

```
list = ['item1a item1b item1c','item2a','item3a item3b','item4a item4b item4c',
'item5a','item6a item6b','item7a item7b item7c','item8a','item9a item9b']
for item, biglist in enumerate(list):
    f=open(outdir_name + "text" + str(item+1)+".txt","w")
    f.write(biglist + "\n".format(list))
    f.close()
```

---

Currently, each nested list is written to a single .txt file. The groupings aren't what I need. I'm so close! I think this should be a minor fix.

For example:

```
text1.txt: item1a item1b item1c
text2.txt: item2a
text3.txt: item3a item3b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job!

```
items_per_file = 3
your_list=['item1a item1b item1c','item2a','item3a item3b','item4a item4b item4c','item5a','item6a item6b','item7a item7b item7c','item8a','item9a item9b']
for item in range(0, len(your_list), items_per_file):
    f=open(outdir_name + 'text' + str((item//items_per_file)+1)+".txt","w")
    f.write("\n".join(your_list[x] for x in range(item, min(item+items_per_file, len(your_list) - 1))))
    f.close()
```

Explanation:

- in the line with the `for`-loop, I am taking steps of `items_per_file`;
- in the `f.open` line, the filename is `item // items_per_file` because without `// items_per_file` you would get `text1, text4, text7, ...`;
- in the `f.write line`, I am writing `items_per_file` items at once;

Update:

- now you can easily change the number of `items_per_file`
- now it also should also work for a `your_list` of eight items (not dividable by `items_per_file`)